# How do I change my armor?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

In Assassin's Creed II, after acquiring Altaïr's armor, I decided to purchase all of the other armor sets, in order to increase the villa's value. It seems, however, that I no longer have access to Altaïr's armor, and now find myself quite vulnerable. As far as I can tell, there's no way to switch between armor, so I'm left with the conclusion that it's lost. Is there anyway to get it back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have access to all your armor back at Villa Monterriggioni. There's an entire room dedicated to it. :)

As you walk up to each armor piece, you should have the option to equip it. You might have to examine it first.

I believe Altair's Armor ends up there as well.